# Trig equation with coefficient and 3x the angle

Tags: trigonometry

Hey guys in my trig class we were given a problem. Here it is below.

"Solve the equation for the exact values over the interval [0,2$\pi$)

$$
8\tan3x=8
$$

My book doesn't explain much, and I have watched endless hours of video, but I don't know where to start on this. Here are the answers.

{$\frac{\pi}{12}$, $\frac{5\pi}{12}$,$\frac{3\pi}{4}$,$\frac{13\pi}{12}$,$\frac{17\pi}{12}$,$\frac{7\pi}{4}$}

I'm familiar with identities and inverse functions, but how would I go about starting to solve this?

Comment: What happens if you let $y=3x$?

Comment: are you sure all of the answer you given are correct? Only 2 of them be correct in the given interval.

Comment: Yea, that was the answers given to me. That's why I'm a little confused

Comment: Thanks, Answer is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Since x $\in [0,2\pi)$, $3x$ $\in [0, 6\pi)$

$8\tan 3x=8 \iff 3x= \tan^{-1}1 $

or $3x = \frac{\pi}{4} ,\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}, 2\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}, 3\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}, 4\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}, 5\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$

or $3x = \frac{\pi}{4} ,\frac{5\pi}{4},\frac{9\pi}{4},\frac{13\pi}{4},\frac{17\pi}{4},\frac{21\pi}{4}$

or $x=\frac{\pi}{12}$ , $\frac{5\pi}{12}$ , $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, $\frac{13\pi}{12}$ , $\frac{17\pi}{12}$ ,$\frac{7\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to $\tan 3x=1\iff3x\equiv\arctan 1=\dfrac\pi4\mod\pi\iff x\equiv \dfrac\pi{12}\mod\dfrac\pi3.$

There remains to write the values of $\dfrac\pi{12}+k\dfrac\pi3$ $(k\in \mathbf Z)\;$ that lie in the interval $[0,2\pi)$.